# onWriteError not working for MongoItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch, itemlistener, spring-batch-job-monitoring, compositeitemwriter

Exceptions are not reaching the `onWriteError` method of my `ItemWriteListener`:

```
public class KeywordsListener implements ItemWriteListener<ClipKeywords> {
    @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends ClipKeywords> items) {
        for (ClipKeywords item : items) {
            log.info(item.getPhoneNum() + item.getKeyword());
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public KeywordsListener keywordsListener() {
    return new KeywordsListener();
}   

@Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<ClipKeywords, ClipKeywords> chunk(1).reader(reader(null))
                .processor(processor()).writer(writer()).faultTolerant().listener(keywordsListener()).build();

    }
```

build.gradle

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version:'1.5.2.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version:'1.47'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version:'1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-batch', version:'1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version:'1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group:'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: working as expected on my end. which version of spring batch are you using? Are you sure an exception is thrown from your writer? Have you tried with another writer?

Comment: I'm using 1.5.2 version and getting DuplicateKeyException

Comment: 1.5.2? There is no such version of spring batch.

Comment: Added build.gradle